# Reading data from object array of arrays in typescript/angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm calling my api which returns me the object array like below.how can I access the array of array object like in below json I want to find out role of roleid =2 when EmpId is 102 using typsecript.

```
0- {
  EmpId: 101,
  EmpName:'abc'
  Role :
     0- {roleid :1, 
         role:Admin, 
         isdeletee:true},

     1- {roleid :2,
         role:user, 
         isdeletee:true},

     2- {roleid :3, role :Admin, 
        isdeletee:true}

}
1- {
  EmpId: 102,
  EmpName:'xyz'
  Role :
     0- {roleid :1, 
         role:Admin, 
         isdeletee:true},

     1- {roleid :2,
         role:user, 
         isdeletee:true},

     2- {roleid :3, role :Admin, 
        isdeletee:true}

}
2- {
 EmpId: 103,
 EmpName:'xez'
 Role :
     0- {roleid :21, 
         role:userx, 
         isdeletee:true},

     1- {roleid :2,
         role:user, 
         isdeletee:true},

     2- {roleid :31, role :ad, 
        isdeletee:true}

},
```

Comment: it will be helpful to understand you requirement if you provide any code which you tried or error that you got on the process..

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand exactly what you want from you question.
Are you looking for something like this? Its just a sample I would add null checks in between in practical use.

```js
const response = [{
    EmpId: 101,
    EmpName: "abc",
    Role: [{
        roleid: 1,
        role: "Admin",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 2,
        role: "user",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 3,
        role: "Admin",
        isdeletee: true
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    EmpId: 102,
    EmpName: "xyz",
    Role: [{
        roleid: 1,
        role: "Admin",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 2,
        role: "user",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 3,
        role: "Admin",
        isdeletee: true
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    EmpId: 103,
    EmpName: "xez",
    Role: [{
        roleid: 21,
        role: "userx",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 2,
        role: "user",
        isdeletee: true
      },
      {
        roleid: 31,
        role: "ad",
        isdeletee: true
      },
    ],
  },
];

const role = response
  .filter((emp) => emp.EmpId === 102)[0]
  .Role
  .filter((roles) => roles.roleid === 2)[0]
  .role;

console.log(role);
```